# How to delete 90 days older record from room database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am trying to delete records older than 90 days but it's not working in `room database`. I have timestamp in mytable. timestamp storing timestamp of record when record inserted. I am storing timestamp in `long` in `room database`.

my timestamps are being inserted please check the image
[image: mytable]

I also tried to do something like this but is also not working for me

```
@Query("DELETE FROM datacaptureinfoalibi WHERE timeStamp <= strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-90 day') )")
int deleteOlderData(/*long timeStamp*/);
```

there are so many solutions available in stackoverflow but non are working for me

Please help me, Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you store the timestamp , perhaps use a tool to view the actual data and include that. ***timestamp storing timestamp of record when record inserted.*** says little **BUT** if you are getting, say the time in millisecs  (`System.currentTimeMillis()`)then `strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-90 day') )` will return null as the data is not stored in a recognised format. You may need to use the `unixepoch` modifier. see https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: please check added table preview data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69523095/10747684) MikeT answer not worked for me

after so many try below query worked for me

```
@Query("DELETE from datacaptureinfoalibi where timeStamp<=:timeStampOfNinetyDays")
int deleteOlderData(long timeStampOfNinetyDays);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your data you are storing the data at the millisecond level `strftime('%s','2021-05-07')` will result in 1620345600 down to seconds, **not milliseconds**.

As such none of the stored timestamps that are displayed will be less than the result of the right hand side of the expression (and wouldn't be way into the future).

So you could either divide the stored value by 1000 to drop the milliseconds.

e.g. `@Query("DELETE FROM datacaptureinfoalibi WHERE (timeStamp /1000) <= strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-90 day') )")` should work *(ex1_seconds below)*

or alternately multiply the right hand by 1000 to add milliseconds :-

e.g. `@Query("DELETE FROM datacaptureinfoalibi WHERE timeStamp <= (strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-90 day') ) * 1000) ")` *(ex3_millis below)*

There is no need for the datetime function so simpler more concise SQL  could be:-

`@Query("DELETE FROM datacaptureinfoalibi WHERE (timeStamp /1000) <= strftime('%s','now', '-90 day')")` *(ex2_seconds below)*

or

`@Query("DELETE FROM datacaptureinfoalibi WHERE timeStamp <= (strftime('%s','now', '-90 day') * 1000) ")` *(ex4_millis below)*

To demonstrate (the right hand side of the expression/comparison) :-

```
SELECT 
    strftime('%s',datetime('now','-90 day')) AS ex1_seconds,
    strftime('%s','now','-90 day')  AS ex2_seconds, 
    (strftime('%s',datetime('now','-90 day')) * 1000) AS ex3_millis,
    (strftime('%s','now','-90 day') * 1000) AS ex4_millis;
```

results in :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can delete orlder than particular time by below query

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date_field <= date('now','-90 day')
```

Comment: already tried but not working for me